# strcmp wrong usage?

Tags: linux, string, strcmp

I am using the following method in order to compare two versions of a same file.

```
fprintf(stdout, "ref_ptr %s\n", str);
fprintf(stdout, "cur_ptr %s\n", cur);

if (strcmp(cur, str) < 0) 
{
    fprintf(stderr,"Error: bad version!\n");
    return -1;
}
```

Output :

```
ref_ptr
01.100
01.020.21
cur_ptr 
01.100
01.000.46
Error: bad version!
```

In this specific case cur is not greater than str, why ?

It works fine when

```
ref_ptr
01.100
01.000.42
```

However, in the first case I would consider 46 > 21

Comment: What are `str` and `cur`? (Sorry, but I'm not familiar with `%r`. And, by the way, why are you using the ancient `%r` instead of the standard `vfprintf`?)

Comment: but `000` is smaller than `020`isn't it? and [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) stops comparing at the first mismatch

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini sorry It was my fault when I wrote the question. It's %s

Comment: @UnholySheep you are right, but I ignored that before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`strcmp` finds the first mismatch between the strings (if it exists) and reports which string has greater value at the point of mismatch.

In your case the first mismatch is here

```
01.020.21 <- str
01.000.46 <- cur
    ^
```

Clearly `2>0` which means `cur` appears before `str` in the lexicographical order so the function call  `strcmp(cur, str)`  should   return negative number.

> `int strcmp( const char *lhs, const char *rhs );`
>
> **Return value**
>
> Negative value if lhs appears before rhs in lexicographical order.
> Zero if lhs and rhs compare equal.
> Positive value if lhs appears after rhs in lexicographical order.